# Testing data set on Angular service after $http call

Tags: angularjs

is there a way to test the data that is set on an angular service after a restful call, here is the service I am setting up. It just has two service calls one to fetch for the widgets and the other to get the widgets, If I then run the test to fetch the widgets, I expect the service to have widgets on a success.

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('myService', function() {
  var service, widgets;
  widgets = void 0;
  return service = {

    widgets: widgets,

    fetchWidgets: function() {
      var promise;
      return promise = $http.get('/fetch/widgets').then(function(response) {
        return widgets = response;
      });
    }
  };
  return service;
});
```

and the test:

```
describe('myService', function() {
  var $httpBackend, service;
  service = void 0;
  $httpBackend = void 0;
  beforeEach(function() {
    module('myApp');
    return inject((function(_this) {
      return function(_$httpBackend_, myService) {
        $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
        return service = myService;
      };
    })(this));
  });
  afterEach(function() {
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
    return $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
  });
  return describe("fetchWidgets", function() {
    return it("should set the widgets on the service", function() {
      var responseData;
      responseData = [
        {
          id: 1
        }
      ];
      $httpBackend.whenGET('/fetch/widgets').respond(function(status, data) {
        return [200, responseData];
      });
      expect(service.widgets).toBeUndefined();
      service.fetchWidgets().then(function() {
        return expect(service.widgets).toEqual(responseData);
      });
      return $httpBackend.flush();
    });
  });
});
```

I keep seeing service.widgets as always undefined, but i see the success block being executed. what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

There are still a few javascript gotchas left to be discovered on this journey. I needed to call a method on the service not directly access the properties. this works:

In the service add this method to access the property:

```
 getWidgets: function() {
    return widgets;
  },
```

And in the test you can now access the values

```
expect(service.getWidgets()).toBeUndefined();
service.fetchWidgets()      
$httpBackend.flush();
expect(service.getWidgets()).toEqual(responseData);
```